# VB.net console - Display the largest number (variable)

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm trying to come up with the code for this question:

***Ask the user to enter ten numbers and then dislpay the largest one***

I have so far come up with this, but looking at how it would be implimented, I can only see errors:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten As String
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your first number")
    One = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your second number")
    Two = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your third number")
    Three = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your fourth number")
    Four = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your fifth number")
    Five = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your sixth number")
    Six = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your seventh number")
    Seven = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your eighth number")
    Eight = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your nineth number")
    Nine = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your tenth number")
    Ten = Console.ReadLine

    If Ten > Nine Then
        Console.WriteLine("Your biggest number is" & Ten)
    Else
        If Nine > Eight Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your biggest number is" & Nine)
        Else
```

I need to see what the biggest number is. Another pupil is using an array to achieve this, but I cannot seem to work them out yet.

So after the user enters the numbers, how can I achieve this?

I tried (above) using If statements, but I see the code being extensive and errors arising if a person enters a larger number at the beginning, and then one at the end, as it would display only the first larger number...

Comment: (we have no yet studied arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an array,

```
Console.Writeline("Number 1?")
Dim Number as integer = Console.Readline()
For Key as Integer = 2 to 10
    Console.Writeline("Number " & Key & "?")
    'Get current number and compare with larger number?
Next
Console.Writeline("Largest number: " & Number)
```

Read this and then try writing it yourself, you'll learn much more that way :)

Comment: Well, you could stop short of actually doing his homework for him :)

Comment: That just hit me after i wrote it :/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that kind of makes sence.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use arrays or collections, I would recommend only keeping the highest value after each input.  For instance, here's some psuedo code:

```
WriteLine("Please enter your first number")
Current = ReadLine
If Current > Highest Then
    Highest = Current
End If
... Do it again
```

Answer (score 1):

There are mainly two approaches:

- Put all numbers in an array and loop through them after all are input.
- Keep track of the largest number during input, so that you compare each new number to the previous highest, and replace it if it is higher.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I'll read up on arrays and see how they function.